# Understanding Mathematica integration solution

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I am trying to understand the result of an integration obtained by using Mathematica software.

$p(x) = \int_0^{\gamma}\frac{2}{A\alpha^2g^2f^2}K_0\left(2\sqrt{\frac{x}{A\alpha^2g^2f^2}}\right)\text{d}x$-----(A)

where $K_0$ is zeroth order modified Bessel function of the second kind and $A,\alpha^2,g^2,f^2,\gamma$ are constant.

The Mathematica solved the equation (A) as

$P(\gamma) = \left[1-\frac{2\gamma K_1\left(2\sqrt{\frac{\gamma}{A\alpha^2g^2f^2}}\right)}{A\alpha^2g^2f^2\sqrt{\frac{\gamma}{A\alpha^2g^2f^2}}}\right]$----(B)

where $K_1$ indicates first order modified Bessel function of the second kind.

I am not getting how eq.(B) is obtained by Mathematica from eq.(A).

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$p(x) = \int_0^{\gamma}\frac{2}{A\alpha^2g^2f^2}K_0\left(2\sqrt{\frac{x}{A\alpha^2g^2f^2}}\right)\text{d}x$$

$$a=\frac 2 {\sqrt{A\alpha^2g^2f^2}}\implies p(x)=\frac 12 a^2\int K_0\left(a\sqrt{ x}\right)\,dx$$

Now $$a\sqrt{ x}=y\implies x=\frac{y^2}{a^2}\implies dx=\frac{2y}{a^2}\,dy\implies \int K_0\left(a\sqrt{ x}\right)\,dx=\frac 2{a^2} \int y K_0(y)\,dy$$
$$\int y K_0(y)\,dy=-y K_1(y)$$

Back to $x$
$$p(x)=-a \sqrt{x} K_1\left(a \sqrt{x}\right)$$ Using the bounds
$$P(\gamma)=1-a \sqrt{\gamma } K_1\left(a \sqrt{\gamma }\right)$$ which seems to be what Mathematica gave (but you need to simplify its result).

Comment: Ok...Thank you for your detail reply...will simplify it and update it here...Once again thank you..

Comment: @Claude: using $K_1$ again neat! :-) Cheers,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni. Thanks & cheers :-)